# Отправляю http-запрос на сервер для получения pdf-файла, но получаю ошибку

Tags: c#, http, url

Я делаю запрос на сервер, чтобы получить в ответ файл PDF. Но я получаю сообщение об ошибке System.InvalidOperationException: «Файл не является допустимым документом PDF» в строке  var document = PdfReader.Open(stream);. Что я делаю неправильно?

```
var myUri = new Uri(url);
    var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
    myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);

    var myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();


    var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
    var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] arr = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(arr);


    responseStream.Close();
    myWebResponse.Close();
    var document = PdfReader.Open(stream);
```

Comment: `1.` Мы не знаем что вам приходит в ответ.
`2.` Не используйте *WebRequest*, он устарел. Используйте *HttpClient*.

Comment: В ответ мне приходит pdf файл @KuzCode

Comment: Понятно, что вам должен прийти pdf-файл, вы это написали, а вот что приходит на деле и хорошо ли всё с ним - не понятно

Comment: У вас, судя по названию переменных в коде, вобще приходит в ответ json, а не pdf

Comment: Можете показать json?

Comment: Приходит ответ ""%PDF-1.7\r%вгПУ\r\n1384 0 obj\r<</Linearized 1/L 65479278/O 1386/E 63894996/N 125/T 65478074/...и тд" @IKuzmichov

Comment: попробуйте сохранить файл на рабочий стол и открыть. Если откроеться - то проблема в коде, если нет - проблема в файле

Comment: @iKuzmichov вы бы обратили внимание, что PDF - не текстовый файл, а он его стримридером как строку читает.

Comment: кстати да) @aepot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вы пытаетесь загрузить двоичный файл как текст, не делайте так.
- Используйте современные инструменты для работы с HTTP.
- [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Не знаю типа авторизации, которую вы используете, поэтому покажу оба основных типа: по логину с паролем, и по токену.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

```
string url = "https://my.site";
string token = "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh";
// string user = "admin";
// string password = "123456";
// string basicToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{user}:{password}"));
Console.WriteLine($"Отправка запроса: {url}");
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
// request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicToken);
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    if (Content.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
    {
        string fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        Console.WriteLine($"Загрузка файла {fileName}");
        using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        // тут можно var document = PdfReader.Open(stream); вместо следующих 2 строк
        using var fs = File.Create(fileName);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        Console.WriteLine($"Файл {fileName} получен.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ответ получен, но это не файл, а '{response.Content.Headers.ContentType}'");
        Console.WriteLine("Вот тело ответа от сервера:");
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка при запросе к серверу: {response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
}
```

Comment: как всегда, лучше всех! Коротко, ясно и полезно для образования!